# Why the accuracy of the same caffemodel is different on OS X and Ubuntu?

Tags: caffe

Why the accuracy of the same caffemodel is different on OS X and Ubuntu? All files are the same. Can anyone give a reasonable explanation?

By the way, I got AlexNet caffemodel from official site `http://dl.caffe.berkeleyvision.org/bvlc_alexnet.caffemodel`. They claim the top-5 accuracy is 80.2%, but I just got 79.9%. What's the problem?

**Environment**

[image]

[image]

**Result**

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you ran test on the entire validation set? random shuffling might cause you to examine different examples on each machine

Comment: Yes, I ran test on MNIST validation set with batch size = 100 and iterations = 100. Is it possible to keep the accuracy consistent on different platforms? Because I want to upload the final caffemodel on github.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem, I have to train some models, while training them on OS 7, the accuracy is decreasing with every iteration. While the same model is trained in Ubuntu the accuracy is not dropping below 98%. I am using caffe in windows 7 and python.

Please take this discussion forward, so more people can address the issue and can give their valuable feedback.